# Drop down menu with HTML / JavaScript price calculation form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to get a drop down menu to work with a price calculation form, but the drop down menu won't add any price value to the total price. I'm pretty bad at doing these things, so maybe one of you knows how to fix this?

This is the [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eWZzbR) to the code.

HTML:

```
 <form action="" id="theForm">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Products
        </legend>
        <label>
            <input name="product" value="12.95" type="checkbox" id="p1" onclick="totalIt()"/>
            Extra domein $12.95
        </label>
        <label>
            <input name="product" value="5.99" type="checkbox" id="p2" onclick="totalIt()"/>
            Verlengservice $5.99
        </label>
        <label>
            <input name="product" value="1.99" type="checkbox" id="p3" onclick="totalIt()"/>
            Domein support $1.99
        </label>

        <select name="product" id="p3" onclick="totalIt()"/>
            <option value="249">Thema 'Ambachtelijk'</option>
            <option value="249">Thema 'Blog - Lifestyle'</option>
            <option value="199">Thema 'Bed en Brood'</option>
            <option value="249">Thema 'Freelancer'</option>
        </select>

        <label>
            Total 
            <input value="$0.00" readonly="readonly" type="text" id="total"/>
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <input value="Submit" type="submit"/>
    <input value="Reset" type="reset"/>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function totalIt() {
var input = document.getElementsByName("product");
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
if (input[i].checked) {
  total += parseFloat(input[i].value);
}
}
document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the problem? So far all I can see is some code... What's wrong? What do you expect to happen? Any console errors?

Comment: I am a bit confused your example totals it up when you select checkbox.

Comment: Your event for the select should be `onchange` instead of `onclick`

Comment: If you open the codepen link, you will see that the drop down menu that I have added, isn't adding any price value to the end price, however I have added value to it in the HTML code.

Comment: You aren't adding the value of select in the `totalIt` function. You loop through the checkboxes but don't add value of select to total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the selected value from `<select>`

And Change `onclick` to `onchange`

> The onchange event occurs when the value of an element has been changed.

Try this:

```
if(input[i].tagName == 'SELECT'){
  total += Number(input[i].options[input[i].selectedIndex].value);
}
```

```js
function totalIt() {
  var input = document.getElementsByName("product");
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if(input[i].tagName == 'SELECT'){
      total += Number(input[i].options[input[i].selectedIndex].value);
    }
    if (input[i].checked) {
      total += parseFloat(input[i].value);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="theForm">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Products
        </legend>
        <label>
            <input name="product" value="12.95" type="checkbox" id="p1" onchange="totalIt()"/>
            Extra domein $12.95
        </label>
        <label>
            <input name="product" value="5.99" type="checkbox" id="p2" onchange="totalIt()"/>
            Verlengservice $5.99
        </label>
        <label>
            <input name="product" value="1.99" type="checkbox" id="p3" onchange="totalIt()"/>
            Domein support $1.99
        </label>

        <select name="product" id="p3" onchange="totalIt()"/>
            <option value="249">Thema 'Ambachtelijk'</option>
            <option value="249">Thema 'Blog - Lifestyle'</option>
            <option value="199">Thema 'Bed en Brood'</option>
            <option value="249">Thema 'Freelancer'</option>
        </select>

        <label>
            Total 
            <input value="$0.00" readonly="readonly" type="text" id="total"/>
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <input value="Submit" type="submit"/>
    <input value="Reset" type="reset"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the code were I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `onchange` instead of `onclick` for select event. The main problem is that you aren't adding the value of select in the `totalIt` func. Might be a good idea to give the select a different id from your 3rd checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your html, you are using same id like p3. Also, you need to handle onchange event. Please see the reference code:

```js
var dropdownTotal = 0;
        function dropDownTotalHandler() {
            var x = document.getElementById("dropdownProducts").value;
                        
            dropdownTotal += parseFloat(x);
               
            document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + dropdownTotal.toFixed(2);
        }
        function totalIt() {
            var input = document.getElementsByName("product");
            var total = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                if (input[i].checked) {
                    total += parseFloat(input[i].value);
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
        }
```

```html
<form action="" id="theForm">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                Products
            </legend>
            <label>
                <input name="product" value="12.95" type="checkbox" id="p1" onclick="totalIt()" />
                Extra domein $12.95
            </label>
            <label>
                <input name="product" value="5.99" type="checkbox" id="p2" onclick="totalIt()" />
                Verlengservice $5.99
            </label>
            <label>
                <input name="product" value="1.99" type="checkbox" id="p3" onclick="totalIt()" />
                Domein support $1.99
            </label>

            <select name="product" id="dropdownProducts" onchange="dropDownTotalHandler()" />
            <option value="249">Thema 'Ambachtelijk'</option>
            <option value="249">Thema 'Blog - Lifestyle'</option>
            <option value="199">Thema 'Bed en Brood'</option>
            <option value="249">Thema 'Freelancer'</option>
            </select>

            <label>
                Total
                <input value="$0.00" readonly="readonly" type="text" id="total" />
            </label>
        </fieldset>
        <input value="Submit" type="submit" />
        <input value="Reset" type="reset" />
    </form>
```

If you want to keep the event handler same, then here is one of the way how you can do it. Hopefully, this is what you want but if not feel free to change it. 
First, change the html to mention totalIt as event handler like below: 
                                                                                                          onchange="totalIt(this.value)"

Then modify the script code. Here, the addition into total is happening for one checkbox at a time:

```
<script>
var total = 0;
    function totalIt(dropDownValue) {
        if (!dropDownValue) {
            total += parseFloat(event.target.value);
        } else {
            total += parseFloat(dropDownValue);
       }
        document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + total.toFixed(2);

    }

 </script>
```

See if this is what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't think you need a different handler function for select. You should be able to use totalIt for both. But if you do you need to account for values of checkboxes to calculate final total.

Comment: This is just a reference code. I can see there many other issues I already pointed like same ids. Additionally, he may cache getElementById calls instead of calculating them in the handler etc.